# sed replace 1st occurence of string after string match on previous line

Tags: replace, sed, line, match

I have a question which I really hope to find the answer.
These is a file with several lines that are the same, but I just want to replace the 1st occurence after a match.

I want to change the first Iam2 to Iwas2 after [blabla] line.

file.txt:

```
Iam  
Iam1  
Iam2  
Iam21  
[blabla]  
Iam3  
Iam2  
Iam3  
Iam2
```

I tried:

```
$ cat file.txt | sed '1,/[blabla]/a \' | sed '0,/Iam2/s//Iwas2/'
```

and also

```
$ cat file.txt | sed '/[blabla]/a \' | sed '0,/Iam2/s//Iwas3/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

One way assuming `infile` with the data of the question:

```
sed -e '
    ## From "[blabla]" until last line try to substitute "Iam2". If the
    ## substitution succeeds go to label "a".
    /\[blabla\]/,$ { 
        s/Iam\(2\)/Iwas\1/; 
        ta 
    }
    ## The substitution didn't succeed, so begin next cycle.
    b
    ## Label "a".
    :a
    ## Substitution succeed, so I don't want to repeat previous process. Now
    ## read each line and print it without modification until end of file.
    N; 
    P; 
    s/^[^\n]*\n//;
    ba
' infile
```

That yields:

```
Iam  
Iam1  
Iam2  
Iam21  
[blabla]  
Iam3  
Iwas2
Iam3  
Iam2
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response.<br/>I tried the commando, but I get an error:<br/>[user@machine]$ sed -e '/\[blabla\]/,$ {s/Iam\(2\)/Iwas\1/; ta } b :a N; P; s/^[^\n]*\n//; ba' file.txt      
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: Extra characters after command

Comment: Are you running it as a one-liner? In that case you must separate instructions with `;`.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'f==1 && /Iam2/{$0="Iwas2";f=0}/blabla/{f=1}1' file
```

Comment: Great solution. I didn't thought about using awk.  Could you please explain the command, about what it is doing. I see that is works, but how? Thx.

Comment: Once you encounter the pattern 'blabla', just set a flag variable 'f' to 1. When you encounter pattern 'Iam2', change it to 'Iwas2' and reset the flag. Since the flag is reset, the further occurence of 'Iam2' will not be touched.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[blabla\]/,/Iam2/!b;/Iam2/!b;s//Iwas2/;:a;n;$!ba' file
```